# Two different kinds of floating-point overflow in Python

Tags: exception, floating-point, overflow

I am testing with calculating `(1e308)**2` and `(1e308)*2` in python. I expect that either

1. both yield overflow,  or
2. both yield `inf`.

However, `(1e308)**2`  manifests an overflow exception while `(1e308)*2` returns `inf` without triggering any exception. Any explanation on why they behave differently? Thanks.

```
In [98]: 1e308**2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-29e84f241b45> in <module>()
----> 1 1e308**2

OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

In [99]: 1e308*2
Out[99]: inf
```

Comment: Mostly just history, along with the fact that backwards compatibility constraints make it hard to change the behaviour here. Some people rely on `1e308 * 1e308` as a way of getting an infinity in the first place.

Comment: See http://bugs.python.org/issue20543 and linked issues for discussion